# Toggle Wrap Mode for 2 Cubes - OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

I have rendered successfully 2 cubes with textures. The first cube is rendered with wrap mode `GL_REPEAT`. For the second cube I want to be able to toggle the wrap mode with a button (for example, when I press 2).

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, cube1tex);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36); // Render the first cube

if (mirrored) {
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_MIRRORED_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_MIRRORED_REPEAT);
} else {
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
}

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36); // Render the second cube
```

I used this code after I draw the first cube, but when I press 2 it toggles the wrap mode for the first cube too. How can I avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

Set the wrap mode for the first cube, before drawing it, as well.

Comment: I updated the code. Still it doesn't work

Comment: @leech Surely that code snippet you showed is not the whole thing (if it were, it would render the two cubes in the very same place). The other parts of the code do matter as well. I suspect, that you might unbind the texture somewhere and don't have it bound when setting the wrap mode for the first cube.

Comment: Of course this isn't the whole code and of course I have applied transformations so the cubes are on different position. I try to check what you said about the texture binding

Comment: I updated the code again. Does this look good? I mean is it okay to use `glActiveTexture()` and `glBindTexture()` first and then use `glTexParameteri()`? Or should I do this the opposite way?

Comment: Yes, the usual order of operations is `glActiveTexture`, `glBindTexture`, `glTexParameter`. Switching texture sampling parameters like you do is the reason while sampler objects have been introduced: https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Sampler_Object – maybe your program gets simpler using those.